# How to enable/disable dynamic form element based on dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dynamic, angular-material, dropdown

I am crating a form view dynamically by iterating over an array of field objects which I am crating them as a part of model object.

```
xyzModel=   [
            { field: 'abc', type: 'text', displayLabel: 'abc', inputType: 'text', isRequired: true},
            { field: 'xyz', type: 'text', displayLabel: 'xyz', inputType: 'text', sRequired: true},
            { field: 'mno', type: 'text', displayLabel: 'mno', inputType: 'text', isRequired: false,},
            { field: 'rsh', type: 'text', displayLabel: 'rsh', inputType: 'text', isRequired: false, },
            { field: 'lyz', type: 'drop_down', displayLabel: 'lyz', inputType: 'text', isRequired: true, },
            { field: 'def', type: 'drop_down', displayLabel: 'def', inputType: 'text', isRequired: true, },
    ]
```

each module have its own model object and can have different fields with different name and values

I am trying to find a solution where I can disable/enable fields based on drop down selected value.

This is how I am creating the form page.

```
<div ng-repeat="field in xyzModel " flex="100" class="p-5" ng-switch="field.inputType">
  <md-input-container class="md-block" ng-switch-when="dropdown">
    <label translate>{{field.displayLabel}}</label>
    <md-select placeholder="{{field.displayLabel}}" ng-model="anotherModle[field.field]"  ng-required="field.isRequired">
      <md-option ng-value="item.id" ng-repeat="item in data[field.Source].data">{{item.value}}</md-option>
    </md-select>
  </md-input-container>
  <md-input-container class="md-block" ng-switch-when="date">
    <md-datepicker ng-model="vm.anotherModel[field.field]" md-placeholder="field.displayLabel" ng-required="field.isRequired">
  </md-input-container>
  <md-input-container class="md-block" ng-switch-default>
    <label translate>{{field.displayLabel}}</label>
    <input name="{{field.field}}" ng-model="vm.anotherModel[field.field]" type="{{field.inputType}}" ng-required="field.isRequired"">
  </md-input-container>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not clear precisely what are you going to get. May you clarify?

Comment: The question is not clear. Does https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled help?